# How to call a another razor-template in razor-template in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a razor-template1 want to use a another razor-template2 just like as partial view.please guide me how is it possible.

Comment: Did you try looking up how to do partial views in Razor? It's better to try than to just ask an overly broad question.

Comment: If you type in 'Partial View' in the search box, here on SO, you should get at least 38,000 results. One of them should most likely give you a starting point in achieving your goal.